# Is it acceptable to have an Adsense unit with height larger than screen height

Tags: google, google-adsense

Currently I find it difficult making money on the mobile portion of my website. Today I look at a page (after sizing my browser window to 375px width) and see the 320x50 advertisement unit nearly takes up the entire width of the screen, because I added margins around the unit to stay in compliance.

What I'm thinking of doing is using a 160x600 ad unit since that's also a Google recommended ad size, but would it cause a violation if I placed that on my mobile site even though that ad unit will likely take more than the user's screen height? (The new unit however isn't expected to take more than half the width.)

Comment: Well, you wouldn't have this issue if your site was responsive. Google [adsense caters for responsive sites](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en-GB). Also, all mobile phones sold in the past 3 years support 600px higher in portrait and landscape mode. In the US and on average people change their phone every 21months, and even less in the UK... Unless you have a high volume of traffic from 3rd world countries (unlikely) then most webmasters would logically agree to focus efforts on the majority and not the minority of users.

Comment: What's wrong with using `336 x 280` for the mobile platform?

Comment: Looking at `pictures.m.clubcatcher` the biggest issue I see is ad placement. Ideally, increase it two or wrap it around the images instead of the text. The highlight of your website is the images, and most people will scroll straight pass the ad.

Comment: So far, I changed my mobile units to 250x250 instead of 320x50 and my RPM went up. It was stalling between 0 and 2 cents RPM with 320x50. I honestly think google uses a low screen width as a factor when evaluating mobile sites. And using 336x280 for mobile exceeds the standard 320px width for mobile and even though google now uses a 375px width in page-speed, 375-336 = not many pixels to squeeze long words at 100% size in.

Comment: `320px` is not standard, its minimal... adopting a design to cater just for Google is bad practice in terms of user experience... no one uses 320px. I'm not saying don't supply this resolution, I'm saying it shouldn't be your target resolution. 600px is standard nowadays.

Comment: Another thing I'd like to say about page speed is a tiny factor, even slow sites rank well... sadly, of course every little helps but anything under 2-3 seconds is acceptable, even with desktop size thumbnails it doesn't slow down mobiles that much, since 3G and 4G are just as fast as 3mbit broadband. Bottomline, top SEO experts believe that Google's factor is around 15-25% for site content inc things like page speed. If you were to do the math on all their factors, your see how little things actually mean... most of ranking factors isn't done on your site.

Answer (score 2):

Just use responsive ad units. They're great for responsive sites but will also work when you have a website that's just for mobile users (e.g. at `m.example.com`).

[image]

I really like how these units adapt themselves to the space available. These days I almost use these exclusively - well together with (maximum 3) 200x90 link units where appropriate.

This also works if you are serving from different URLs for desktop and mobile.

Comment: I would try that if I had only one URL to serve desktop and mobile but I like to keep my mobile site rather lean for optimum performance.

Comment: Responsive ad units work very well, also if you're only serving to mobile.

Comment: I remember reading from google policies that I'm not allowed to use responsive ads because I have a separate desktop/mobile site instead of a single URL for both versions. I'm gonna look for that policy again.